# how to find finite union of closed sets which can approximate a compact separable metric space?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have falled into a confusion when i read a book. Its statement is

Let $S$ is a complete separable metric space,Given $\epsilon > 0$, by separability, for each $n$, there exists a finite collection $\{F_{n,k}\}^{k_n}_{k=1}$ of closed sets of diameter not exceeding $n^{-1}$ and such that $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^{k_n}F_{n,k})^c < \epsilon/2^n$.where $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $S$.

Please help me to fill this gap.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: This is not true. You have written union instead of intersection.

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry, I find i make some typing mistakes. It is $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^{k_n}F_{n,k})^c$ instead of $\mu(\cup_{k=1}^{k_n}F_{n,k}^c)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of separability, there exists a countable dense set $A=\{a_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset S$. By density, for each natural number $n$, the collection $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B(a_i,n^{-1})$ equals $S$, here $B(a_i,n^{-1})$ denotes the closed ball of radius $n^{-1}$ centered around $a_i$. By the fact that $\mu$ is a probability measure we have
\begin{align*}
1&=\mu(S)\\
&=\mu\left(\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}B(a_i,n^{-1})\right)\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^kB(a_i,n^{-1})\right).
\end{align*}
So, in particular, there exists a $k_n$ such that $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^{k_n}B(a_i,n^{-1})\right)>1-\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$; showing that
$$\mu\left((\bigcup_{i=0}^{k_n}B(a_i,n^{-1}))^c\right)<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}.$$
If we pick $F_{n,k}=\{B(a_i,n^{-1})\,:i\in\{1,\dots k_n\}\}$ then the job is done.

Comment: awesome! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_i)$ be  a countable dense set in $S$. Then $S=\bigcup_i \overline B (x_i,\frac 1 {2n})$ where $\overline B (x,r)=\{y\in S: d(y,x) \leq r\}$. Now $\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} \overline B (x_i,\frac 1 {2n})$ increases to $S$ so $1=\mu (S)=\lim_{m \to \infty} \mu (\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} \overline B (x_i,\frac 1 {2n})$. Hence, there exist $k_n$ such that $\mu (\bigcup_{i=1}^{m} \overline B (x_i,\frac 1 {2n})>1-\epsilon/2^{n} $. Now take $F_{i,n}=B (x_i,\frac 1 {2n})$.

Comment: awesome, Thanks for your help!